# Full text search in Neo4j, is it possible to get the score?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to use cypher to perform the query in full text index. It returns results, but they are not ranked. Is there a way to get the match score?

`start recordEmployee=node:fidx_RecordEmployee("F01:Leela* OR F01:Ph*") return recordEmployee.F01`

Returns this, and I cannot find match score:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "columns": [
        "recordEmployee.F01"
      ],
      "data": [
        {
          "row": [
            "Philip"
          ],
          "graph": {
            "nodes": [],
            "relationships": []
          }
        },
        {
          "row": [
            "Leela"
          ],
          "graph": {
            "nodes": [],
            "relationships": []
          }
        }
      ],
      "stats": {
        "contains_updates": false,
        "nodes_created": 0,
        "nodes_deleted": 0,
        "properties_set": 0,
        "relationships_created": 0,
        "relationship_deleted": 0,
        "labels_added": 0,
        "labels_removed": 0,
        "indexes_added": 0,
        "indexes_removed": 0,
        "constraints_added": 0,
        "constraints_removed": 0
      }
    }
  ],
  "errors": []
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible in Cypher yet, but with stored procedures in Neo4j 3.0 it will be again.

Until then if you really need the score you can use the REST endpoint.

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-indexes.html#rest-api-find-node-by-query

> Getting the results with a predefined ordering requires adding the
>   request parameter
>
> `?order=<ordering>`
>
> where `<ordering>` is one of `index`, `relevance` or `score`. In this case an
>   **additional field will be added to each result, named score**, that holds
>   the float value that is the score reported by the query result.